# Mongodb query to find all the keys where value is in list of object

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

i am stuck middle of my project, i want to find _id where userIdList have  object id = 5f95576b150c8a9a5421bf89. please let me know is there any way in mongo query to find such kind of data or in python

```
  {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5f955499163841c4abaf6d93"),
        "userIdList" : [ 
            {
                "id" : ObjectId("5f955753150c8a9a5421bf88")
            }, 
            {
                "id" : ObjectId("5f95576b150c8a9a5421bf89")
            }, 
            {
                "id" : ObjectId("5f95603fae1acd4383f96fca")
            }
        ]
    }
    
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5f955559163841c4abaf6d94"),
        "userIdList" : [ 
            {
                "id" : ObjectId("5f95601bae1acd4383f96fc8")
            }, 
            {
                "id" : ObjectId("5f95602bae1acd4383f96fc9")
            }
        ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply query on **userIdList.id** mongodb will return the matched document if any of the element in array matches the query

```
from bson import ObjectId
db.COLLECTION_NAME.find({ 'userIdList.id': ObjectId("5f95576b150c8a9a5421bf89") })
```